# Font double px value what represent?

Tags: css

Maybe my question is simple or not, but I did some research and I cannot find anything about it.

I reading an article and I have find the following in an example:

```css
font: 27px/27px Baskerville, Palatino, "Palatino Linotype", serif;
```

What does the `27px/27px` represent ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first is the size, the second is the line-height.

```
font: size/line-height;
```

See the [CSS specification for the font shorthand property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/fonts.html#font-shorthand) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

The first part represent the font-size and the second part represent the line-height.

Check it out:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_font.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_font-size.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_line-height.asp